# SSH using IPV6 getting error "No Route to Host" in Mac OS X 10.10.1

Tags: macos, ssh, ipv6

I am trying to SSH with IPv6 in Mac OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite) but I am getting error

> No Route to Host"**

I can do it successfully with IPv4. Can anyone guide me please if it require any network setting or else?

Comment: I am using command is "ssh username@My_Ipv6_Address" Yes I can ping. I have done with command "ping6 -I en0 -c 1 My_IPV6_Address". It shows result like "1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss"

Comment: what OS is the other machine, is its sshd listening on ipv6?

Comment: @vautee Other machine also have same Mac OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite) Yes, when I ping getting result same as above comment "1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss"

Comment: Erm, you asked on about _how_many_ different stackexchange sites? Sir, that's quite some spamming indeed :)

Comment: okay let me check and thanks for reply. sorry, I have asked on four sites :-). Well, Not much aware about networking funda so to get guidance from anywhere..Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal as root on your destination mac, have a look at the output of `lsof -i | grep ssh` and look if there's at least one IPv6 line. If not, it's not listening on v6.

Comment: There is no single line for IPV6, means it's not listening. Thanks but to listen it is there need any changes from network configuration or from network provider?